# Beginner in JS,Stuck with ChartJS and multiple filters and ways to display

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Before I explain my problem, I just wanna apologize for the wording of the question, I didnt know how to word it properly.

Here's my problem. **I want to display a chartJS about the evolution of the quantity of a product, by week, month & year.** The issue is : I have six products like that. The only solution I have in my mind, is destroying a graph and re-creating one for each possibility. Which... is I bet **terrible**. To choose what product to show, I have created a SelectBox where you choose the product. From there, I'll like to display the corresponding chartJS. The only solution I have found "possible" was using RadioButtons and then verifying the different combinations with a switchcase.

Does someone has a more feasible idea to fix this concept's issue ? Thanks a lot in advance and I apologize for my broken english.

EDIT : AS asked by @AndrewL64, here is an example of my code used to change the type of the graph after a click on a button. It is not exactly what I want to do for the final product, but it shows easily the issue I am running into. It is a total mess. And this is only for ONE product and three types of graph. I've read about ChartJS that you cant update its type and you have to recreate it.

```
function changeGraphType(type){
var gradctx =  document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");

let gradient = gradctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

//gradient bar & line
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'orange');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'purple');


graphique.destroy();

if(type==='pie'){
    graphique = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), {
        type: type,
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Ceci est un test',
                data: donnee,

                backgroundColor: gradient,  //['#FF3254','#85ff2d','#ffdb0f','#FF3254','#FF3254','#FF3254','#FF3254','#FF3254','#FF3254'],
                hoverBackgroundColor:'rgb(252,10,19)'
            }],
        },
    });
}
else if(type==='line'){
graphique = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), {
    type: type,
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Grillage blindax',
            data: donnee,

            backgroundColor:gradient,
        }],
    },
});
}
else{
    graphique = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), {
        type: type,
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Test',
                data: donnee,

                backgroundColor:gradient,
                hoverBackgroundColor:'rgb(64,252,52)'
            }],
        },
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added a code snippet about one of the issues im running into.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **select** and the box will be changed too.
if you need more boxes just add a new **div** with **class** *box* and some **id** but note you have to add **option** too and the **value** must be the same **id** of the box to relate to each ohter.

I hope that can help.

```
<div class="box active" id="chartJS-1">Box 1 is here</div>
<div class="box" id="chartJS-2">Box 2 is here</div>
<div class="box" id="chartJS-3">Box 3 is here</div>
<select id="select">
    <option value="chartJS-1" selected>chartJS-1</option>
    <option value="chartJS-2">chartJS-2</option>
    <option value="chartJS-3">chartJS-3</option>
</select>


.box {
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(121, 3, 105);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    display: none;
}
.box.active {
    display: block;
}


const select = document.querySelector('#select');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
select.onchange = _ => {
    let value = select.value;
    boxes.forEach(box => box.classList.remove('active'));
    document.querySelector(`#${value}`).classList.add('active');
};
```

Comment: Hello, I think my issue is about handling the Chart with ChartJS, because i've read that I have to recreate a chart everytime I want to change the type or the data, labels...